# Proof of convergence and $C^1$ class $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n^2x}$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, power-series

I have a problem to prove that this function:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n^2x}$$

takes every value in its domain and is $C^1$ class in $x\in(0,\infty)$.

The steps I have to take is to check the convergence of the power series and the uniform convergence of the power series. I have proven the alomst uniform convergence of the series of the derivatives, however I have the problem with **pointwise** convergence (I have excluded uniform convergence) and the **continuity**. I would appreciate your hints.

Comment: What means *takes every value in its domain*?

Comment: To. prove that the function is well defined and belongs to $C^{1}$ it is enough to prove this in $[r,\infty)$ for each $r>0$. In this interval the series as well as the series of derivatives converge uniformly.

Comment: In my language, it is literally  *well described*, but maybe I  should edit it to *contiunous*.

Comment: By almost uniform convergence, you mean uniform convergence on any closed intervals?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, could be expand your calculations? I have tried proving convergence in the intervals, but it failed for me.

Comment: @Jakobian, yes, convergence on any closed intervals

Comment: $\sum n^{2}e^{-n^{2}r}$ is convergent so $\sum f_n'$ is uniformly convergent by M-test.

Comment: Right, the derivative also worked for me. However, I need the convergence of $f_n(x)$, not the derivative

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

By [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) $g(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^\prime(x)$ and $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ are uniformly convergent on every compact $K \subseteq (0,\infty)$ where $f_n$ is the continuous map $x \mapsto e^{-n^2x}$.

therefore according to [Differentiation and Uniformly Convergent Series of Functions](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/differentiation-and-uniformly-convergent-series-of-functions) theorem, $f$ is continuously differentiable on each compact $K \subseteq (0,\infty)$ and consequently on $(0,\infty)$ itself.

As each of the $f_n$ is positive decreasing on $(0,\infty)$, $f$ is positive decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.

Moreover the inequalities $0 \le f_n(x) \le e^{-nx}$ valid on $I=(0,\infty)$ imply
$$0 \le f(x) \le \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}$$ and therefore $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Finally, taking $x_m = \frac{1}{m^2}$ we get
$$f(x_m) \ge \sum_{n=m+1}^{2m} e^{-k^2/m^2} \ge m/e^4.$$ This implies that $f$ is unbounded. **As $f$ is continuous, its image is equal to $(0,\infty)$.**